# Zend 2: Update a partial view using Jquery?

Tags: zend-framework2, partial-views

I have a partial view:

```
echo $this->partial(
    'site/testimonials/partial.phtml', 
        array()
);
```

Is there an easy way to refresh the contents of this view using Jquery? In YII you could do something like this:

```
$.fn("somePartial").update();
```

Or something similar. Can that be done with zend 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax request to the Server, Response with rendered HTML but no Layout and then update the innerHtml of your Container (that's where the partials are inside). Done. No inbuilt support for this kind of thing.